# Error from posting datas from form using PHP

Tags: php

I was wondering could u help me resolve my PHP problem.
I made a PHP script that writes data from form in new row.
But, when i run script it says
`Undefined index: name`
I am still beginner of PHP but i hope u will help me.
Thanks any way.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "error". mysqli_connect_error();
}
$name=($_POST['name']);
echo "ime: ".$name;



?>
<form method="post" action="go.php">
FIrst name: <input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit" value="send"?>
</form>
```

Comment: When the form is not submitted, $_POST['name'] is not defined. That is when you are getting the error. You can check whether current request is a post by `if (!empty($_POST))`

Comment: Thanks u dude!U gave me idea!I used `if(isset($_POST['send']))` and that resolves my problem.Now everything is perfect.Thank u again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it inside this if statement

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

     $name=($_POST['name']);
    echo "ime: ".$name;


 }
```

Comment: Thank u, friend above gave me idea so i made is just as u wrote it.Thank u again :D

Comment: If it answers your question, mark it as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['name'] is not defined if you don't submit the form. So, try to type something into the textarea and click on "send": this error won't appear.
Otherwise, you can tell php to consider $_POST['name'] only if it's set, updating your code like this:

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "error". mysqli_connect_error();
}
if(isset($_POST['name'])){$name=($_POST['name']);
echo "ime: ".$name;}



?>
<form method="post" action="go.php">
FIrst name: <input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```